# how to open a specific controller after tapping on push notification when the app is terminated or killed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, swift2

Actually what I'm trying to do in my app is, I'm setting an alarm for the notification and then I'm terminating the app forcibly.Now when the notification comes and I'm tapping on it, it just opens the app and not the specific controller which I want to open (HoroscopeNotificationViewController) whereas after setting the alarm if the app runs in the background, then on tapping the notification the specific controller's opening and working fine.

Your help will be really appreciated..Thanks in advance

```
func application(application: UIApplication,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
if let _:UILocalNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification {

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.showNotification), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

let firstCategory:UIMutableUserNotificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    firstCategory.identifier = "FIRST_CATEGORY"
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    print("MessagesID : \(userInfo["gcm_message_id"]!)")
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(application: UIApplication,
                 handleActionWithIdentifier identifier:String?,
                                            forLocalNotification notification:UILocalNotification,
                                                                 completionHandler: (() -> Void))
{

    if (identifier == "FIRST_ACTION")
    {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("actionOnePressed", object: nil)
    }
    else if (identifier == "SECOND_ACTION")
    {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("actionTwoPressed", object: nil)
    }

    completionHandler()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("MessageId: \(userInfo["gcm_message_id"])")
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    if #available(iOS 8.2, *) {
        print("Function goes here : \(notification.alertTitle)")
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    if notification.category == "FIRST_CATEGORY" {
        sleep(8)
        let horoscopeNotificationObj = window?.rootViewController?.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HoroscopeNotificationViewController") as! HoroscopeNotificationViewController
        window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(horoscopeNotificationObj, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

func showNotification() {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("modifyListNotification", object: nil)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the view controller's not loaded in memory yet. Try calling `myController.view` to force the view controller to be loaded into memory before trying to show the view controller.

Comment: Zhang , could you please help me where to load the HoroscopeNotificationViewController.Is it in Appdelegate?If yes then where to load and how, if you kindly help me in details with the code, then I'll be highly obliged.

Comment: Aren't you the one who created the app? You should know where it is. Press Cmd-Shift-O to bring up a search field, then type the name of your controller.

Comment: No sir, my query is where to load the controller in Appdelegate

Comment: @SirsenduDas pls accept answer if this solution work for you !!

Answer (score 1):

To open a specific view controller on tap of notification in terminated state or killed state, you need to check existence of launch option object in app delegate method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions params. Please refer this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

if let localNotification: UILocalNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification { 
    //launchOptions is not nil
//if this will not work then call this below method when application root view controller is ready to handle child view transition or just do a sec delay
                self.application(application, didReceiveLocalNotification: localNotification)
            }
```

Comment: pls accept answer if this solution works for you @Sirsendu Das

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your effort to solve my query.
Instead of using "NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.showNotification), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)" and "func showNotification() {NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("modifyListNotification", object: nil)}"
 I've just simply pushed the controller from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to the specified controller using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier and it worked for me.
Thanks once again @Sachin and @Zhang

Answer (score 0):

**

### SWIFT 4

**

```
 let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatView") as! ThreadViewController

        let threadIdToPass = JSON(notificationData)["threadId"]
        nextViewController.threadId = threadIdToPass.intValue
        print("App Delegate thread data \(threadIdToPass.intValue)")
        let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

        navigationController.show(nextViewController, sender: Any?.self)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

if let localNotifcation: UILocalNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.localNotification] as? UILocalNotification {

         let NotificationInfo = (launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.localNotification])!

     self.application(application, didReceive: NotificationInfo as! UILocalNotification)
}
```